# Angular Cli - Url editable en producción

Tags: angular-cli

Tengo una pequeña aplicación en producción en angular 7, y por curiosidad me di cuenta que por ejemplo, si ingreso directamente con el nombre de mi dominio me lleva al login de la aplicación ya que internamente esta establecido de esa forma.

Pero si yo le ingreso por ejemplo: www.midominio.com/login manualmente... me sale objeto no localizado.

A lo cual me lleva a la pregunta ¿hay alguna forma dentro de angular para poder hacer editables en producción las rutas, evitando que salga ese mensaje de error?

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solucionado: Gracias a los que estuvieron atentos a este hilo... ya pude encontrar la respuesta.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172138/angular-6-route-path-not-working-for-direct-url-when-deployed-in-subdirectory/51200924

Comment: ¿Puedes ponernos el fragmento de código donde tienes definidas tus rutas?

Comment: Puse dos imagenes para hacer mas entendible mi duda

Comment: ¿Estás usando stack mean? ¿Tienes sólamente programada la parte del front? Pon también la parte de tu código donde defines las rutas de tu aplicación con sus respectivos componentes.